# How can I tell which gummi enemy encounters have been completed?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

When exploring the world map in a gummi ship, there's enemies that can be fought. I've already defeated most enemies in Straight Way Galaxy, so I am trying to find the ones I haven't encountered yet.

Is there a way to tell if I have completed an enemy encounter?

Comment: I want to say there is list of encounters somewhere in the gummi ship menu, but I can't verify this at the moment in time.

Comment: There is a list of encounters you've completed and the score, but it doesn't exactly tell you where these encounters are. I'm looking for a way to tell if an enemy ship flying in the space is already a completed encounter or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to Faxter's answer, you can add a marker to already completed missions. So if you see an enemy, with the help of the starts + the markers you can realise if you already completed it. You don't even have to leave the menu, as the marker shows even while you are paused.

I know it's not much, but it really seems like the developers just totally missed that feature.

Comment: That is a very good addition.

Comment: You don't even need to leave the pause menu. Look at the enemy, pause, and mark the one you think it is. Go back one, and see if your marker is on it. If not, rinse and repeat until you find it, or you realize it's a new one.

Comment: I didn't realize you can put markers on the enemies from the list :o I'll have to test this tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem and here is what I found out so far:

When travelling in the inter-world space with your ship, there is no sure-fire way to tell if you have already completed a mission that you see in front of you or on the mini-map with the Heartless-symbol.

You can however look at your Gummi mission list by opening your menu and selecting Information > Gummi Records. It will show you the star-rankings of all missions in your current area. That way you can at least see which kind of star-rating the missions have that you still need to find.

**For example:**
In your Gummi mission list, you can tell that you still need a mission that is rated with three red stars. Flying around space, you now know that you can skip anything that has a different star rating than the one you are looking for (e.g. five red stars or three orange stars).

I know that is not very satisfying, but as far as I can tell - there is nothing better the game is offering you.

**Last tip:**
Gummi missions appear to spawn in the same location every time. So if you keep track of where you already where, you should be able to tell if you already did a certain mission based on their location.

Comment: I already used these tips myself, was hoping for a better way... :/

Answer (score -1):

Gummi ship missions/ fights that haven't been done or completed will blink red like crazy.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to upload a photo showing what im about to express but my mobile isnt very happy with it.
Im not 100% sure but i believe the colour of the stars underneith the heartless marker tells you if its completed or not. 
After a few battles i only seem to get full rewards from orange starred battles. Red stars seem to be ones ive already done and net only exp. If someone else can confirm it would be much appreciated but hope this helps ^-^

Comment: This is untrue.  Orange stars mean regular enemy missions, red stars mean boss type fights.